# why nvme device name is nvme1c1n1, not nvme0n1?

Tags: disk, nvme

I got this message:

```
systemd-udevd[3364]: nvme1c1n1: Failed to get device name: No such file or directory
```

when doing `lsblk`, there is no `nvme1c1n1`, only `nvme1`

I didn't change/create a partition on this nvme.

Comment: Why are you concerned with the name? Also, what's kernel output in `dmesg` regarding the initialization of this device and what `lspci` and `nvme-cli` think about it?